# Could there be a split slit experiment for gravity?

Tags: gravity

Gravitons seem to still be a hypothetical entity in particle physics. If true, then gravity exists as a wave and a particle like photons.

Could an experiment for gravity similar to the traditional split slit photo experiment either be constructed or occur in nature? What would physically occur for two gravity waves to cancel out? Any ideas on how we would even observe this?

Comment: In what opaque-to-gravity material do you plan to cut out your slits?

Comment: Dunno. That’s why I’m asking. Maybe you could get something that is equivalent using massive objects that bend gravity in special configurations naturally.

Comment: Actually, the double-slit experiment does not require an opaque material.  A phase mask having the same form as a double slit will produce the same interference pattern -- it just has a strong "DC" background.

Comment: It could be done with 2 paths around a gravitational lens. All you need is a galactic cluster, some well placed merging blackholes, and a giant array of LIGOs. Coherence length may be an issue.

Comment: Actually it has been done. At the center of gravity, GWs cancel out and you feel weightless.